# Numerical instability due to convection dominated PDE

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

I am trying to solve this partial diffusion equation$$\dfrac{\partial\overset\sim\rho_c}{\partial\overset\sim t}=D_c(\overset\sim r)A\left(\dfrac{\partial^2\overset\sim\rho_c}{\partial\overset\sim r^2}+\dfrac2{\overset\sim r}\dfrac{\partial\overset\sim\rho_c}{\partial\overset\sim r}\right)$$Here is what I have tried.

```
sol = NDSolve[{D[Csol[r, t], t] == 
A*(D[Csol[r, t], r, r] + (2/r) D[Csol[r, t], r]) + 
 NeumannValue[0, r == 0], Csol[r, 0] == 1, 
DirichletCondition[Csol[r, t] == 0, r == 1]}, 
Csol, {r, 0, 1}, {t, 0, tref}, 
Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
"MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.0001}}]
```

It evaluates fine, and plotting the function returns

```
Grid[
 Partition[
  Table[Plot[Evaluate[concentration[r, t]], {r, 0, 1}, 
    PlotRange -> {0, 1}, FrameLabel -> {"r", "Concentration"}, 
    PlotLabel -> "t = " <> ToString[t]], {t, 0, tref, tref/10}], 5], 
 Spacings -> {10, 2}]


Plot[Evaluate[concentration[r, tref]], {r, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 1},
  FrameLabel -> {"r", "Concentration"}, 
 PlotLabel -> "t = " <> ToString[tref]]
```

[image]

However a warning pops up showing: The PDE is convection dominated and the result may not be stable. Adding artificial diffusion may help. I would like a solution that does not require the addition of artificial diffusion as this would effect the nature of the diffusion equation.

Comment: Please give the values of all parameters `A, tref,...`to make your code run

Answer (score 1):

Try `MethodOfLines`

```
A = 1;
tref = 2;
sol = NDSolveValue[{D[Csol[r, t], t] == 
A*(D[Csol[r, t], r, r] + (2/r) D[Csol[r, t], r]) + 
NeumannValue[0, r == 0], Csol[r, 0] == 1, 
DirichletCondition[Csol[r, t] == 0, r == 1]},Csol, {r, 0, 1}, {t, 0, tref}, 
Method -> { "MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t, 
"SpatialDiscretization" -> { "FiniteElement","MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> .01}}}]  


Plot3D[sol[r, t], {r, 0, 1}, {t, 0, tref }, PlotRange -> All,MeshFunctions->(#3&)]
```

[image]